# Why does IsAssignableFrom() not work for int and double?

Tags: c#, .net, types

This is false: `typeof(double).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int))`

This is false: `typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double))`

But this works:

```
double a = 1.0;
int b = 1;

a = b;
```

Clearly a `double` *is* assignable from an `int` but the framework `IsAssignableFrom()` gets it wrong.

Why? Or is this a bug in .NET caused by the special nature of `int` and `double` which have no inheritance relationship but are assignable (in one direction)?

Comment: I guess it doesn't take into account implicit casting.

Comment: From the [IsAssignableFrom MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

Returns "true if c and the current Type represent the same type, or if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the current Type is an interface that c implements, or if c is a generic type parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints of c. false if none of these conditions are true, or if c is a null reference."

Comment: Thanks all; I've added a community note to MSDN making this hidden corollary somewhat clearer lest anyone else foolishly assumes that the method name means what it says.  I guess `Type.IsSomewhatAssignableFrom` would have been too long :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

C# is providing the implicit conversion from `int` to `double`. That's a *language* decision, not something which .NET will do for you... so from the .NET point of view, `double` *isn't* assignable from `int`.

(As an example of why this is language-specific, F# *doesn't* perform implicit conversions for you like this - you'd need to explicitly specify the conversion.)

It's worth looking at the documentation for [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) (edited very slightly for readability):

> Returns true if c and the current Type represent the same type, or if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the current Type is an interface that c implements, or if c is a generic type parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints of c. Returns false if none of these conditions are true, or if c is null.

Now apply that to `double` and `int` and you'll see it *should* return false.

Comment: Is `IsAssignableFrom()` a language feature or a framework feature?  If it's a language feature, why wouldn't it do what its name says it does?  Yes, if you read the small print on MSDN it never actually says that it checks for assignability but the name misleads one into thinking that it ought to.

Comment: @Hightechrider: It's a method call (and not within any sort of language-specific namespace), so it's clearly a framework feature.