# Generics explicit conversion

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I implemented an explicit conversion from string to object called Foo.

So =>      **Foo f = (Foo)"foo data"; works**

I need to implement a function that cast a string to the generic T, T in this case is Foo datatype.

```
public T Get<T>(object o){
      // this always return false
      if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(String)))
      {
            // when i by pass the if above this throws invalid cast exception
            return (T)(object)str;
      }
      return null; 
}

// When I call this, it generated an error
// Invalid cast from 'System.String' to Foo
Foo myObj = Get<Foo>("another foo object"); 

// when I use the dynamic keyword it works but this is C# 4.0+ feature, my function is in the older framework
return (T)(dynamic)str;
```

Comment: You should use `TypeConverter`s instead.

Comment: What is the definition of `Foo`? Does it have `implicit` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or `explicit` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operators overloaded?

Comment: @CodingWithSpike Foo has explicit conversion Foo itm = (Foo)"string"

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8172220/1069200) might be helpful but not a solution.

Comment: It looks like the compiler doesn't know that `T` will have a user provided `explicit` operator, so simply casting `(T)str` won't compile. If you constrain your generic to `Foo` then it builds and works fine, but that defeats the purpose of the generic, since you can then only specify `Foo`. Looking for a way to trick the compiler into allowing this...

Comment: what happens if you do `return o as T;`? That would give you the same "return null if not convertable behavior"

Comment: @AaronLS that wouldn't compile.

Comment: @DuD. Compiles fine for me.  Posted full console app as example.

Comment: @AaronLS my T doesn't have any constrain that y it doesn't compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example that uses Reflection:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        Foo myObj = TypeResolver.Get<Foo>("Foo data");            
    }
}

class TypeResolver
{
    public static T Get<T>(object obj)
    {
        if (typeof(T).CanExplicitlyCastFrom<string>())
        {                             
            return obj.CastTo<T>();
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool CanExplicitlyCastFrom<T>(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        var paramType = typeof(T);
        var castOperator = type.GetMethod("op_Explicit", 
                                        new[] { paramType });
        if (castOperator == null)
            return false;

        var parametres = castOperator.GetParameters();
        var paramtype = parametres[0];
        if (paramtype.ParameterType == typeof(T))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static T CastTo<T>(this object obj)
    {            
        var castOperator = typeof(T).GetMethod("op_Explicit", 
                                        new[] { typeof(string) });
        if (castOperator == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException("Can't cast to " + typeof(T).Name);
        return (T)castOperator.Invoke(null, new[] { obj });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need, thanks!!!
var castOperator = type.GetMethod("op_Explicit", 
                                        new[] { paramType });

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275764/why-does-isassignablefrom-not-work-for-int-and-double/6275787#6275787) from @Jon Skeet - and specifically the quote about `IsAssignableFrom`.

I don't think that's possible in a way that you envisioned it.

I'd suggest you put an 'interface contract' on your Foo classes - and then let generics do their work.

e.g. something like this - but this is just a fast solution I typed in...

```
class Factory 
{
    public static T Create<T, TVal>(TVal obj) where T : class, IFoo<TVal>, new()
    {
        return new T { Value = obj }; // return default(T);
    }
}
interface IFoo<TVal>
{
    TVal Value { get; set; }
}
class Foo : IFoo<string>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Foo() { }
}
// ...
public T Get<T, TVal>(TVal obj) where T : class, IFoo<TVal>, new()
{
    return Factory.Create<T, TVal>(obj);
}
```

And you can call it in a similar way - providing that you `have that luxury` - know the types etc.
(but you can work this out and adjust if needed)

```
Foo foo = Get<Foo, string>("another text");
```

Comment: So Type.IsAssignableFrom is out of the question for this. Unless i'm going to implement conversion using other methods.

Comment: I'm afraid so - also explicit / implicit don't seem to kick in, in a similar way, in the 'generics world' (we need Eric to explain the inner workings here). With interfaces you can actually enforce your generics to listen to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you go via `(object)` then it just does a type-check cast or a box/unbox (in IL terms: an unbox-any) - it will not use operators. The only way to use generics and operators together is via `(dynamic)` instead of `(object)`, but this does a little work at runtime.

Comment: I mentioned that in my last line, dynmic is c# 4.0 feature I'm stuck in the older framework.

Comment: @DuD. then you cannot do it via generics; that is the only way. The point about generics is that the same IL applies to all types. That doesn't work for operators.

Answer (score 0):

This is *reallllly* ugly, but the test passes:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest2
    {
        public T Get<T>(string str)
            where T : CanCastFromString<T>, ICanInitFromString, new()
        {
            return (T)str;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            var result = Get<Foo>("test");

            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(Foo));
            Assert.AreEqual("test", result.Value);
        }
    }

    public class Foo : CanCastFromString<Foo>
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override void InitFromString(string str)
        {
            Value = str;
        }
    }

    public abstract class CanCastFromString<T> : ICanInitFromString
        where T : CanCastFromString<T>, ICanInitFromString, new()
    {
        public static explicit operator CanCastFromString<T>(string str)
        {
            var x = new T();
            x.InitFromString(str);
            return x;
        }

        public abstract void InitFromString(string str);
    }

    public interface ICanInitFromString
    {
        void InitFromString(string str);
    }
}
```

You can trick the compiler into knowing that your generic `T` can be explicitly cast from `string` by defining it on an `abstract` class `CanCastFromString` then constraining your `Get()` generic function to that abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you defined T at the class, but either way I have it on the method.  This works if you can handle a class constraint on T.

```
namespace TestCast {
    class Program
    {
        public static T Get<T>(string o) where T : class
        {
            return o as T;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Get<Breaker>("blah");
        }
    }
}
```

It returns null if the conversion is not valid, just as in Du's question he returns null if can't convert.  For a string, this will work in limited scenarios.  The `as` operator will also **not** utilize user defined conversion operators.

Comment: My method doesn't have any contraint on T. To make my post simpler I didn't show other type of conversions in the method.

Comment: I don't mean to undermine you here :) but I don't think this works - `this returns null` actually. It does compile though.

Comment: It returns null if the conversion is not valid, just as in Du's question he returns null if can't convert.  It wasn't clear from the original unedited question what some of the surrounding requirements were.  This does work, but in limited cases.

Comment: Isn't `null` a constraint itself?

Comment: What I'm talking about is - if `Foo is class` and reference type. And with explicit or implicit operators defined. This passes the compilation (irrelevant though) - but `as` dosn't recognize operators and returns null. I tried on an example.