# C# type cast from my type to my other type

Tags: c#

My code gets an object with everything in it. And as per different needs, it needs to be cast to different individual type.

```
class A
{
    public static explicit operator B (A value)
    {
        ....
        return new B();
    }
}

class B
{
    ...
}

public static T Get<T>(...)
{
    A a = new A();
    return (T)A;
}

var b = Get<B>(...); // cannot convert a type of A to B
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're talking about converting, not casting. You will have to write code to do that, for example by mapping property to property.

Comment: T is not B and has nothing in common

Comment: @JohnWu: Well the conversion operator allows a cast expression to call the custom conversion. I don't think it's unreasonable to use the term "cast" here.

Comment: Maybe reading about the [explicit keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) helps you out here.

Comment: C# is a statically typed language, meaning that arbitrary casting/conversion is not allowed. Your classes must be somehow related, through some level of inheritance, or a common interface, in order to be able to perform an operation like that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough. I admit I didn't look at their example very closely and what you're saying makes sense now that I have.

Comment: Related: [Generics explicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114226/generics-explicit-conversion)

Comment: @ArashMotamedi: Only because of generics being involved. It's entirely possible to cast between unrelated types, if there's a custom conversion operator provided, as there is here. For example, `var b = (B) new A();` would work. It's the generics part that's getting in the way here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this, as the compiler doesn't know (and there's no way to tell it) that there's a conversion from `A` to `T`. You'd need to constrain `T` in some way to indicate that, and you just can't do that - in the same way that you can't constrain `T` to have a `+` operator etc. (The C# team has been considering how what that might look like and how it might be implemented, but it's definitely not available at the moment.)

You need a way of telling the compiler how to convert from an `A` to a `T` - you could add a parameter to `Get` to tell it that:

```cs
public static T Get<T>(Func<A, T> converter)
{
    A a = new A();
    return converter(a);
}
```

You'd then call it with:

```
var b = Get<B>(a => (B) a);
```

for example.

Answer (score -1):

C# doesn't support duck typing, but you could serialize your class A into a json string, then deserialize it into class B, any any properties that have the exact same names and types (or via a mapping you set up using JSON attributes or JSON settings) will make their way into class B as desired.

Comment: ooo ooo @Jon Skeet what do you think of this idea?

Comment: I suspect that going via JSON would be problematically slow in several cases, and remove object identity aspects (e.g. in properties) that might also cause problems. I think using reflection to find the converter would probably be better - but I'd probably use a delegate, as per my answer